# In react.js is there any way to disable all children events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build an application which has two states; pause and active. For example I want to disable all children/owned components' events like onClick, onChange, onKeyDown, .etc.

I had thought to give `isActive=false` prop through all it's children/owned components and check for the property `isActive` on event handlers. If `isActive` property is falsy event handler will do nothing. I can make this mechanism even easier with a simple helper function. But my concern is when I changed the app state to paused, all children components needs to be re-rendered.

Im searching for a way to bypass all event handlers (not custom ones) without re render all components.

UPDATE: I watch rendering rectangles on chrome end it doesn't re render the children. But if there any better reacty way to do this I want to learn it.

Comment: Have you considered a transparent (or very slightly opaque grey) absolute positioned div in front of the UI to "cover up" all the controls when paused? It would intercept all events. I don't know react, so not an answer. But its's easy in js.

Comment: Yes that was my second thought but events are not limited to mouse events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to solve this is using a simple guard abstraction.  It works like this:

```
var sayHi = guard("enabled", function(){
  alert("hi");
});

guard.deactivate("enabled");
sayHi(); // nothing happens
guard.activate("enabled");
sayHi(); // shows the alert
```

Using this for event handlers is similar:

```
handleChange: guard("something", function(e){
  // if 'something' is deactivated, the input won't change
  this.setState({value: e.target.value});
})

// or

return <div onClick={guard("something", this.handleClick)}>click me!</div>
```

Here's an implementation of guard

```
var guard = function(key, fn){
  return function(){
    if (guard.flags[key]) {
      return fn.apply(this, arguments);    
    } 
  };
};

guard.flags = {};
guard.activate = function(key){ guard.flags[key] = true };
guard.deactivate = function(key){ guard.flags[key] = false };
```

Answer (score -1):

Set `pointerEvents='none'` in the styling of the container div.  It'll disable all of the children.  I know it from React Native, but it seems to work in React.js as well.

Comment: This solution keeps popping everywhere but this only prevents mouse clicks and finger clicks.

On the browser, you can still tab and interact with the elements. In other words pointerEvents does not prevent keyboard events.

Comment: why does everyone seem to forget that tab navigation and enter key is a thing.

```jsx